# Skype always shows me online even when it's not running

Tags: skype

A few days ago, I downloaded Skype for Android. I made the mistake to uninstall it without logging off first, and now on the desktop version I am always shown as online even if there is no instance of Skype running.

I already tried to install the Android application again, to log in, log off and uninstall the application with no result.

On the desktop, I also removed the %appdata%/Skype folder, also with no result. Finally, I already tried the `remotelogout` command, and the `showplaces` command is giving me only one online endpoint, my computer. I changed my password too.

I would like not to need to set my status manually to offline every time I need to shut down Skype.

Is there any way I can fix this from my desktop computer?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solution (from [Solution for SKYPE ALWAYS ONLINE](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Solution-for-SKYPE-ALWAYS-ONLINE/td-p/2962914)):

> Use these commands in a chat window with any person:
>
> /showplaces - Lists other instances where this Skype name is currently signed in.
>
> /remotelogout - Sign out all other instances except the current one. This will also stop push notifications on all other instances.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I already tried this and it's not working for me =/

Comment: The `/showplaces` commands returns me a single device, yet I'm logged in on two devices.